# Отправка сообщения в чат через textarea, jQuer/js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chrome-extension, textarea

Пишу расширение для Chrome. На таргетном сайте есть чат, в который нужно периодически отправлять сообщение. Проблема в том что input реализован через textarea, отправка идет по нажатию Enter:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как именно реализована отправка сообщений, и возможно ли сделать отправку программно?

```
<div class="chat-footer">
        <textarea placeholder="Введите ваше сообщение..." maxlength="200" tkey="placeholder-chat-textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Comment: сделать клик по кнопке? `$('button').click()`

Comment: @Tsyklop нет баттона, только текстареа

Answer (score 0):

Тебе надо сгенерировать событие нажатия `Enter` на элементе `textarea`
Например так

```
// keyKode 13 как раз и есть клавиша Enter
var event = $.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 13} );
// Сгенерировать созданное событие на элементе
$('.chat-footer textarea').trigger(event);
```

Естественно подразумевается, что ты уже подключил в расширение библиотеку jQuery

Comment: Это первое что я сделал, но насколько я знаю то что выше не запускает событие привязанное к объекту, например если таким образом кликнуть по ссылке ничего не произойдет

Comment: Это я для примера код привел, который генерирует нажатие enter на textarea (В тестовой реализации, когда есть обработчик `keydown` на поле, работает). Но в реальной ситуации посмотри именно в инспекторе firefox (в хроме инспектор не показывает, какие события конкретного DOM элемента обрабатываются, например https://yadi.sk/d/Y00BAp-V3SjChE),  на какие события подписано это поле. Возможно это `keyup`, либо есть валидация поля

Comment: Нашел, там keypress, но все равно не отправляет, код выполняется, ошибок в консоле нет.

Comment: Сайт - https://csgojustice.ru/ 
Правда интересно почему не работает, я просматривал документацию, и там все то же что и вы писали